# Apache Axis Webservice on Wildfly 9

Tags: jboss, wildfly, axis, wildfly-9

I am migrating my JBoss from 4.0.5 to WildFly 9.0.2 release, But I have one Axis web service based on (WSDD) based, but I don't know how to deploy it on WildFly,

When I call some method using 
org.apache.axis.client.Call then it is not working.

Does anyone knows about it?